# I want my Grid-view Check box is checked always on Checked checkbox true in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a table t1, and table t2 . My gridview is populating against value of t1. in t1 checkbox on every row if checkbox is check t1 insert entire row in t2 table and it save data.
i want my inserted row data is saved in t2 and commpare with t1 and then checkbox of compared rows are checked.
any hwlp will be appreciated:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
        CheckBox Chbox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chb1");

        if (Chbox.Checked == true)
        { 
            select++;
        }
    }
    if (select == 0)
    {

    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {

        string id = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
        string name = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
        string City = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text;
        string Age = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text;
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
        CheckBox Chbox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chb1");


        if (Chbox.Checked == true)
        {
            con.Open();
            com = new SqlCommand("insert into info2 values('" + id + "','" + name + "','" + City + "','" + Age + "')", con);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            foreach (GridViewRow grow in GridView1.Rows)
            {

                int id1 = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);

                con.Open();
                com = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM info where id='" + id1 + "'", con);
                SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                CheckBox ChkBoxRows = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chbl1");
                if (dr.Read())
                {

                    Response.Write(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].ToString());

                }


                //if (dr = 1)
                //{
                //    Chbox.Checked = true;

                //}
                //else
                //{
                //    Chbox.Checked = true;
                //}


                //com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
```

Comment: paste some code what you tried

Comment: int id1 = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);

                    con.Open();
                    com = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM info where id='" + id1 + "'", con);
                    SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                    CheckBox ChkBoxRows = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chbl1");
                    if (dr.Read())
                    {

Comment: Ganesh_Develekar please provide me email id i will send you.